# Show the Trace$(B)^{2} \leq$ nTrace$(B^{T}B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, trace, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

The following definition is needed for my actual question:

For $A, B \in \mathcal{M}_{n \times n}$ define
$$
 \langle A, B \rangle = \text{Trace}(B^{T}A) = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_{ij} \, a_{ij}
$$

And here is the actual question:

For $B \in \mathcal{M}_{n \times n}$ show that
$$
\text{Trace}(B)^{2} \:\leq\: n \,\text{Trace}(B^{T}B)
$$

I know I have to use the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality, but I wasn't exactly sure how to.  Here is my attempt:

Since I only have one matrix I decided to use the identity matrix
$$
\begin{align}
\text{Trace}(B)^{2} \:&\leq\: n \,\text{Trace}(B^{T}B) \\
\text{Trace}(I^{T}B)^{2} \:&\leq\: n \, \langle B, B \rangle \\
\langle I_{n}, B \rangle^{2} \:&\leq\: n \, \Vert B \Vert^{2} \\
\langle I_{n}, B \rangle \:&\leq\: \sqrt{n} \, \Vert B \Vert
\end{align}
$$

I feel like I either did it incorrect, or that I'm close but am missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you pretty much have the solution:
$$
\operatorname{trace}(B)^2 = 
\overbrace{\langle I,B \rangle^2 \leq
\langle I,I \rangle \langle B,B \rangle}^{\text{Cauchy Schwarz}}  =
\operatorname{trace}(I) \operatorname{trace}(B^TB) = 
n\operatorname{trace}(B^TB)
$$
So, we have
$$
\operatorname{trace}(B)^2 \leq n\operatorname{trace}(B^TB)
$$
which is what we wanted.

Comment: That was kind of my thought, but isn't adding the $\langle I, I \rangle$ on the right hand side not algebraically legal?  Wouldn't I have to add one to the left hand side too?  I guess it's not a big deal to add it to both sides because if I'm not mistaken according to the definition in the beginning of the question $\langle I, I \rangle = \text{Trace}(I^{T}I) = \text{Trace}(I) = n$

Comment: I don't understand where anything is being "added on the right side"

Comment: Ohh, never mind.  I thought you added $\langle I, I \rangle$, but you just rewrote $n$ as $\langle I, I \rangle$.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$\text{Tr}(B)^2 = \left(\sum_{k=1}^n B_{kk}\right)^2$$
$$(B^TB)_{ii} = \sum_{j=1}^nB^T_{ij}B_{ji} = \sum_{j=1}^n B_{ij}^2$$
Hence,
$$\text{Tr}(B^TB) = \sum_{i,j=1}^n B_{ij}^2$$
From Cauchy-Schwarz, we have
\begin{align*}
\text{Tr}(B)^2 & = \left(\sum_{k=1}^n 1 \cdot B_{kk}\right)^2 \leq \left(\sqrt{1^2+1^2+\cdots +1^2} \right)^2 \left(\sqrt{B_{11}^2 + B_{22}^2 + \cdots + B_{nn}^2}\right)^2\\
& = n \left(\sum_{i=1}^n B_{ii}^2\right) \leq n \text{Tr}(B^TB)
\end{align*}